# Symfony 2 - files not gzipped when cache set to public

Tags: php, symfony, http-headers, gzip

I have strange behaviour in prod env. I set in `php.ini`

```
zlib.output_compression = On
zlib.output_compression_level = 6
```

On `http://mysite.dev/` everything working fine:

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Age 0
Cache-Control   public, s-maxage=60
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

but on production `http://mysite.prod/` it doesn't:

```
Age 0
Cache-Control   public, s-maxage=60
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  2951
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Have no idea where to search a solution.

#### Edit:

Found the problem, i have enabled `AppCache.php` wraper in `web/app.php`:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
```

Is this possible that cached files stored in `app/cache/prod` are not parsed by php (ommit `zlib.output_compression`)?

Comment: Are both requests processed with one server?

Comment: Yes, I use Hiawatha, both configuration is the same.